# PhoneApplicationFrame customization has no effect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to customize a PhoneApplicationFrame in some way but I don't understand how do I have to proceed.

Let me explain a little : I'm working on a WP 8 application which I want to have a background sound and sound effects (simultaneosly). After asking help, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515823/play-background-sound-and-sound-effect-in-windows-phone-8), I have been advised of using a `MediaElement` and add it in the `XAML` of the `PhoneApplicationFrame` (is this correct?).

What have I done in this matter :

I created a frame (called IntroFrame) and set it as the `RootFrame` in `App.xaml.cs` file. So it is :

```
public partial class App
{
    public static IntroFrame RootFrame {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

And in the `InitializePhoneApplication` method, I adapted the code :

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
   ...
   RootFrame = new IntroFrame();
   RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
   ...
}
```

In the XAML, I tried to add the `MediaElement` :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationFrame
    x:Class="PazaakPhone.IntroFrame"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <MediaElement x:Name="BackgroundMedia" Source="Assets/Audio/bgm.mp3" AutoPlay="True" /> 
</phone:PhoneApplicationFrame>
```

The Frame seems fine, I tried the height trick like [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/phoneapplicationpage) and it worked. However, I tried to customize that Frame, to add visual elements, to change that MediaElement and nothing... no effect. I guess `PhoneApplicationFrame` can't have content like a `PhoneApplicationPage`? I thought I could do this in the background while the Frame, hosts all the other pages. But either I am on the wrong path or I am missing something. What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by re-templating the PhoneApplicationFrame:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myPhoneApplicationFrameStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                    <Grid x:Name="MediaElementContainer" Margin="0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MediaElement" Source="Assets/Audio/bgm.mp3" AutoPlay="True" Volume="1.0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ClientArea">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and then setting the style in the app.cs:

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
        return;

    RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame { Style = Resources["myPhoneApplicationFrameStyle"] as Style };
    RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
    RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

    // Ensure we don't initialize again
    phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cadessi for the answer. Altough it did solve the problem with running the sound, it takes me to the MainPage and shows only the header (title) and the rest of the page content is not shown. I was trying to modify the styling so that all the page is shown but whatever modifications I make, it always results into an exception.

Comment: Since the MediaElement is Collapsed, any page shown in the frame should be getting the whole screen. Please, try the code above with a new empty Windows Phone App.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for the MediaElement to play a background sound. But it seems many controls just disappear from the UI - listbox, listpicker, images and so on. All UI elements seem to disappear if I set explicitly the HorizontalAlignment property. All the pages in my app are in landscape mode, would that interfere with some default properties of the style?

Comment: Also I would need to constantly have access to the MediaElement, which I don't know how to refer to it. How to do that?